# как сделать с View separator Line разделители между Label?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, separator

Не могу разобраться как сделать сделать справа возле  label такие разделители Линии  вертикальные в stackView. Вот пытаюсь сначала сделать хотя бы возле одной.Очень буду благодарен за подробную статью.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        let line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:lineView.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: lineView.frame.size.width, height:2 ))

        line.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        lineView.addSubview(line)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var lineView: UILabel!





}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Я бы воспользоваться [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) на нее положил бы 3 UIView и в средней по краям положил еще UIView шириной в 1pt - это и будут твои разделители.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку попробую.Но я хотел бы кодом сделать.

Comment: @ShurikTennisist https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit тебе в помощь.

Comment: Та я не хочу эти Pods  устанавливать....